# Prove that the limit is $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left(\frac{1.4.7\dots .(3n-2)}{2.5.8\dots .(3n-1)}\right)^2 $$

Here I want to show that the limit is $0$.
I tried the ratio test, but it fails as it comes to be $1$.

I have no idea how to do this, please help.

Comment: What makes you think that limit is zero?

Comment: I supose that, in denominator, the $3$ is $5$

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I think the second term in the denominator is supposed to be 5, not 3.

Comment: Maybe Raabe test or some other tests that derived from the comparison with the $\zeta(p)$?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake i have edited it now

Comment: Or, the big gun: Gamma function along with Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 2):

**Possible hint**

The problem is "simple" if you know or remember that
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(a i+b)=a^n\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+1-\frac{b}{a}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(1-\frac{b}{a}\right)}$$ Apply to numerator and denominator and simplify. Then, take logarithms, use Stirling approximation for $\log(\Gamma(x))$.